Seed recovery from paper wallet
My friend has found a file that seems to be a Bitcoin paper wallet backup, but it has quite strange seed encoding that I have never met before. It has:

A field named "Key" - a short string (11 chars) with letters and digits
90 numbers each 6 digits

Does anyone know how to decode such type of paper wallet?

Is your friend sure this is Bitcoin related? What makes them think that?

I'm not sure. This file is named Bitcoin, and inside, it has instructions to print it on paper to backup

Because the exact instructions etc might help identify the file, it might help if you edited the question to include a modified copy of the whole file that has the 11-character key replaced by XXXXXXXXXXX and each of the 90 6-digit numbers replaced by NNNNNN (and same for any other numbers/strings that might need to be confidential)
